# Infinite Loading on HTTPS Request with Asp.Net Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, https

When I try to make an HTTPS request with my Razor Page eg. a POST request then comes in the console:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost [2]
Request finished in 103.9478ms 200 text / html; charset = utf-8
```

but the website just keeps loading and I will not be redirected to the index page

here is the code from the post method

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            if (this.RegisterViewModel.Password == this.RegisterViewModel.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                var profileResult = await this.dbContext.Profiles.AddAsync(new Profile
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Created = DateTime.Now,
                    Modified = DateTime.Now
                });

                var userResult = await this.userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = this.RegisterViewModel.UserName,
                    Email = this.RegisterViewModel.Email,
                    ProfileId = profileResult.Entity.Id
                }, this.RegisterViewModel.Password);

                if (!userResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid credentials.");
                    return Page();
                }
            } else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Passwords dosen´t match.");
                return Page();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("/Index");
        }
```

Comment: Are you making post request via Ajax?

Comment: Must be some java code running on the webpage.